# how to chose an option using jquery when option is not displayed

Tags: jquery

I have this select statement:

```
     <select id = "selectLanguage" name="language"
     <option value="any" lang="English">All</option><option value="any" lang="French">Tous</option>
     <option value="french" lang="English">French</option><option value="any" lang="French">Français</option>
     <option value="english" lang="English">English</option><option value="any" lang="French">Englais</option>
     </select>
```

in css:

```
*:lang(English), *:lang(French) {
display: none;
}
```

later on the user will choose which language he needs and at that time I will diplay the appropriate elements using show().

In jquery is it possible to select the first option of each select depending on which language is shown?

Now what happens it that language select always displays ALL for example

Comment: Not reliably.  `display:none` usually means the element is not there, for many intents and purposes.  Why not make the selection when you actually display the element later?

Comment: @Brad, what do you mean? yes I don't mind doing this, I just don't know how to do this in jquery :$

Comment: When you do `.show()`, add a part that also sets `.val()` as well.

Comment: mm I can't, cause show() is done in a utility file somewhere else (out of my control)

Comment: Fortunately, with JavaScript, there are many ways you can override things, even if the other plugin is out of your control.  What are you calling on this plugin to make it show the form?  Can you add the code there instead?  If not, you could always monkey-patch something, but I can't help you with that as I don't know what this other utility file out of your control is/does.

Comment: The form is generated staticaly on the html page... from the top the user can chose his language and by that all the element with appropriate lang property will be shown and the other hidden

Comment: Everything works as expected except that the first element shown in the select box is always the first one defined and not the first one shown...

Answer (score 0):

To select the first option in a select list, try looking at jQuery's [.first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/)

```
var first = $('select option').first();
```

To select the selected option in a select list, try looking at jQuery's [:selected Selector](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/)

```
var selected = $('select option:selected');
```

To select the option with a particular attribute, try looking at jQuery's [Attribute Equals Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
var english = $('select option[lang="English]');
```

Combining these to get the first English selected element, we get:

```
var engSelected = $('select option[lang="English]:selected')
```

**Edit:**
It looks like your HTML attributes are not set up correctly, try this:

```
<select id = "selectLanguage" name="language">
  <option value="any" lang="English">All</option>
  <option value="any" lang="French">Tous</option>
  <option value="french" lang="English">French</option>
  <option value="french" lang="French">Français</option>
  <option value="english" lang="English">English</option>
  <option value="english" lang="French">Englais</option>
</select>
```

**Note:**

You can also refine your selection by attributes, like this:

```
var engEnglish = $('select option[value="english"][lang="English"]');
```

Comment: I tried that but for example in the #language select, "ALL" is always selected regardless of the language chosen.

Comment: @Kam, see my suggestions for your HTML options and jQuery selection by multiple attributes.

Comment: When I type this in a document.ready handler, nothing happens...$('select option[value="english"][lang="English"]');

Answer (score 0):

See this

```
$("#selectLanguage option[lang=French]:visible").first().prop("selected","selected");
$("#selectLanguage option[lang=English]:visible").first().prop("selected","selected");
```

Comment: I mentioned this idea in the comments... apparently it can't be done because the file is "out of their control".